# How do I reference a capture group in Xcode 11's Find and Replace?

Tags: regex-group, xcode11, backreference, find-replace

After creating a capture group using the `+` button in Find and Replace in Xcode 11 I can't figure out how to reference that group in the "With" field. No matter which field is focused when I click the plus button the reference is always added to the "Replace" field.

Answer (score 1):

You need to double click the group in the "Replace" field in order to insert it at the caret in the "With" field. That wasn't very discoverable.

I expect I will return to this question...regularly.